# What SDK should I use for DirectX 11?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, windows-7, directx

I am very confused on what I need in order to use the latest version of the DirectX SDK.

There is the DirectX SDK (June 2010), which is apparently deprecated and there is the Windows SDK for Windows 8.1.

What is so confusing is that I can't figure out if the Windows SDK for 8.1 will work using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop, or if I have to use the DirectX SDK (June 2010) with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop.

Also, if I use Windows SDK for 8.1, how do I include it in my Visual Studio Projects. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

The DirectX SDK has been rolled into the Windows SDK starting with version 7.0. Unless you need certain deprecated features such as DXUT, specifically the runtime shader compiler, you'll be fine just running with the Windows SDK.

If, however, you want to use the deprecated features of the DirectX SDK, you'll need to include *both* SDKs, with the Windows SDK set to have higher priority than the DX SDK. If you include both and see a redefinition warning, then you included them in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop (or VS 2013 Pro or better), then you have the Windows 8.1 SDK and will use it for any C++ project by default. To support 'down-level' systems such as Windows 8.0, Windows 7 and/or Windows Vista, you need to set the _WIN32_WINNT preprocessor symbol [appropriately](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) (_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 for Windows 7 or later). There's nothing else special you need to do, and you can use DirectX 11.0, DirectXMath, XInput 9.1.0, etc. on all these platforms without any need to use the legacy DirectX SDK. The [HLSL compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx) (D3DCompile #47) DLL is available in the Windows 8.x SDK to just copy into your apps folder for Win32 desktop apps, although on Windows 8.1 it is already part of the OS as well.

[Where is the DirectX SDK (2013 Edition)?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx)

[Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk.aspx)

Ideally you would avoid using D3DX11 and use any of the many [alternatives](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx) available that support Win32 desktop apps on Windows Vista or later.

You can of course still **also** use the legacy DirectX SDK with the Windows 8.x SDK (which unfortunately you have to for [XAudio 2.7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx) on Windows Vista/Windows 7; XAudio 2.8 is part of Windows 8.x), but you need to remember that the include/lib path order is **reversed** since the headers in the DirectX SDK are now older than those in the Windows 8.x SDK. This is covered on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). Remember that if you use the legacy DirectX SDK components like D3DX, XAudio 2.7, XInput 1.3, XACT, D3DCompiler #43, etc. then you also need to rely on the legacy DirectSetup deployment. In this case, it is recommended you make use of the [refreshed version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/04/19/dxsetup-update.aspx) of the REDIST rather than the one that shipped in the legacy DirectX SDK.

BTW, if you are trying to target Windows XP with the "v120_xp" Platform Toolset, you are actually using the Windows 7.1 SDK and not the Windows 8.x SDK since the Windows 8.x SDK does not support Windows XP. See this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1.aspx) for the many caveats of this scenario, or save your sanity and just let Windows XP go away :)

Comment: Note I said "DirectX 11.0" above. You can use DirectX 11.1 on Windows 7 SP1 with KB [2670838](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838) but remember that not all DirectX 11.1 features are available on Windows 7, and that older installs of Windows 7 and Windows Vista have DirectX 11.0 only. See this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj863687.aspx) for details.